# Simplifying $(r\lor p) \land ((\lnot r \lor (p \land q)) \land (r \lor q))$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

How to simplify the proposition $(r\lor p) \land ((\lnot r \lor (p \land q)) \land (r \lor q))$ using propositional algebra?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Hi, Rodi, what had you try so far?

Comment: Although tedious, a truth table may significantly help.

Comment: $[(r\lor p) \land ((\lnot r \lor (p \land q)) \land (r \lor q))]
\\\equiv [(r \lor p) \land (r \lor q) \land (\lnot r \lor (p\land q))]
\\\equiv [(r \lor (p \land q)) \land (\lnot r \lor (p\land q))]
\\\equiv [(r \land \lnot r) \lor (p \land q)]
\\\equiv [\text{False} \lor (p \land q)]
\\\equiv (p \land q).$